# UINavigationController usage when not the main/root view

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller

I'm having a bit of trouble wrapping my head around using a UINavigationController (with Interface Builder) when it isn't at the root of the application.  I've found many examples which demo how to use one of these controllers when it is at the root of the application (in MainWindow.xib); however, my app is not structured this way.  I have a UIScrollView which is my main display.  From the scroll view screens I have a "settings" button.  When that button is pressed I want the next view controller shown to be a screen which has a UINavigationController.  This screen is your typical "settings" screen with a grouped table.  Once a cell is tapped the nav controller will push another controller on to the stack which contains the relevant settings options.

My main problem is understanding how to implement the UINavigationController in this scenario.  If anyone has any examples or advice it would be greatly appreciated.

Please do not simply point me to Apple documentation on View controllers or Navigation controllers.  I have already read these documents and i'm still not getting it.  I need some real help and advice.

Comment: I'm currently wondering the same thing. Unfortunately, it looks like you didn't get much help.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you need to re-read those documents, specifically the documentation on `UINavigationController`.

The point that you miss is that you do not *implement* a `UINavigationController`. You *use* that class and push your own viewcontroller on it.

You also seem to confuse a `UINavigationController` for a `UITableViewController. The two are completely different. Your settings would be implemented as a`UITableViewController`subclass and pushed on a the`UINavigationController`.

Comment: The problem for me was not one of semantics.  Implement, use... whatever... It also had nothing to do with confusing a nav controller with a tableview controller.  I was trying to set it up in IB thinking that was easiest.  In reality it was easiest to just do it in code.